# Third party .h files included all over my code

Tags: c++

I gathered a bunch of definitions from multiple third party .h files.

```
    // my_header.h
    #include   "thrd_party_header1.h"
    #include   "thrd_party_header2.h"

    #define MY_DEFINE_1     THRD_PARTY_DEFINE_1
    #define MY_DEFINE_2     THRD_PARTY_DEFINE_2
    //etc...
```

Problem is that now each class file including `my_header.h` "sees" all those 3rd party includes. I don't want that. What can I do to minimize the headers used in my .cpp?

Comment: Only include the headers where you need them? Wait for the library implementer to move to modules?

Comment: Would like it to be easy to change those low level defines in case low level changes

Comment: Define your version and then `#undef` the original. Sidenote: `#define`s are a very stupid tool. If you're going to mask them, replace them with `constexpr` variables at the same time so you get type checking, namespaces, and other compiler goodies.

Comment: Depending on the nature and complexity of third party code, another possibility is to write your own class(es) that wraps the third party stuff and hide the headers and other low level details in your class implementation cpp file

Comment: why don't you move those headers to .cpp files? Resort to pimpl if needed

Comment: What are you using from the third-party headers? Can you hide/wrap those things so you only need to include them from your .cpp?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
//my_header.h
#ifdef SEE_DEFINES
#include "thrd_party_header1.h"
#include "thrd_party_header2.h"
#endif
```

Then you can include my_header.h without seeing the third party headers, and when you want to see them just do

```
#define SEE_DEFINES
#include "my_header.h"
#undef SEE_DEFINES
```

Comment: Not really. Your code prevents them from being defined more than once, and a good header would have prevented that anyway with include guards, but in order to get the definitions, the header needed to be included and once included, a header stays included.